# How to combine two or more QuerySets from different models and order objects chronologically?

Tags: python, django

I have two querysets I need to combine and iterate through the objects chronologically, based on a `datetime` field which is common to both models. What is the best way to do that ?

I'm able to combine querysets with `union` but objects are not sorted properly.

```
model_combination = model_set1.union(model_set2, all=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#union), `order_by` is supported by union. Try like this:

```
model_combination = model_set1.union(model_set2, all=True).order_by('datetime_field')
```